# Seeking Guidance on Constrained Input Modeling for Soil Moisture Correction Using Rainfall Observations

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, convolutional-neural-network, image-preprocessing

I find myself immersed in the intricacies of working with 2D modeled fields (images) representing soil moisture in regions where direct observations are unfortunately absent. However, there is a silver lining—I possess observational data for rainfall within the same geographic areas. My primary objective is to elevate the precision of soil moisture predictions by integrating rainfall observations as a crucial constraining factor.

My current contemplation revolves around the adoption of a CNN regression approach for my inverse modeling problem. In this envisioned model, the input comprises the modeled soil images, while the output corresponds to the rainfall values across various time steps. It's noteworthy that this application deviates from conventional CNN models; here, the focus is on refining the accuracy of soil moisture predictions (inputs) rather than generating predictions for rainfall (outputs).

This methodology appears reminiscent of inverse modeling or Bayesian models. I am eager to seek your valuable insights and expertise, particularly if you can provide suggestions for alternative models or methodologies that might be better suited to my purpose.

I express my gratitude in advance for your contributions.

Answer (score 0):

> observational data for rainfall

Well, clearly temperature, cloud cover, and dew point are going to matter, as well.
I assume you can readily obtain such figures.

> CNN regression approach

Given the timeseries nature of precipitation
followed by vegetation growth and evaporation,
it's unclear why this would be the winning tool to draw from the (Polya?) toolbox.

---

Various folks systematically gather the sort of data you are interested in.
You may find this article on
[soil moisture](https://web.archive.org/web/20230403154648/https://www.nytimes.com/2023/04/03/climate/california-storms-snowpack.html)
measurements helpful.

In the Sierra Nevada range,
snowpack measurements are invaluable for predicting summer reservoir levels.
But putting vegetation specimens in a desiccating oven
[can also](https://www.nwcg.gov/publications/pms437/fuel-moisture/live-fuel-moisture-content)
be helpful, for assessing what summer wildfires will look like.
Mass of sample before versus after desiccation indicates
how much water the sample originally contained.

Such measurements have been conducted in a standard way for many years.
LANDSAT and similar imagery is available for the subject areas for many years.
So you may be able to exploit this ground truth to train a "pixels to liters"
model of how much water is visible within the orbiting camera frame.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to address my query. I don't have a predefined modeling approach and am open to suggestions, excluding CNN. It's important to note that my study area faces a challenge of limited surface measurements, with rainfall being the only available data.

Beyond the data constraints, my personal interest lies in exploring machine learning and deep learning for this project. Any guidance in this context would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Well, Ground Truth is always a big deal. Avoid exploring areas where GT is unobtainable. We always want to be able to validate our model, for example by training on 1990 - 2009 rainfall + images, and then validating 2010 - 2019 image predictions against known historic rainfalls. // I mentioned a few government sponsored data collection efforts. Undoubtedly there are many more. Consider taking on a project where, in the "wrong" region of the world, data is available and you make "good" predictions. Then pivot to another region where data is less plentiful, yet you are armed with a strong model.

Answer (score 0):

What if you consider a multi-modal approach? From the context I assume you have images and some tabular data, then what if you use an autoencoder to extract information from the images, and then use the tabular dataset in conjunction with the extracted data,

So you end up with say,

Image -> CNN -> vector representation of image,
(vector representation of image, tabular data) -> regression.

I don't know if this would work, but it would be my initial instinct to try.

Comment: Thank you for your response. However, I'm unsure if your solution takes into account any potential impact or optimization for the input based on the performance of the model.